# Can I use Automator or some other method to extract EXIF GPS data from batches of photos on my Mac?

Tags: photos, automator, gps, exif

I need a way of extracting EXIF GPS data, using my Mac, from a bunch of photos taken on an iPhone.  So for example, if I put 1000 photos into a folder, I want an easy way of extracting all the GPS data for each photo into a text file.

A solution which gets me close will probably be good enough.  I've looked at Automator but don't see a built in way to do what I need.  I have Aperture, iPhoto and Photoshop CS4 on my Mac in case someone knows a way of incorporating those applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Commandline tools this is easy:

- Install [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)
- `brew install exiftools`  in the Terminal
- `find ~/Pictures/ -iname '*.jpg' -print  -exec exiftool -DateTimeOriginal -GPSLatitude -GPSLongitude {} \;` in the Terminal

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of CLI utilities and scripting libraries available in Fink, MacPorts, and Homebrew available to extract and manipulate EXIF data.

Comment: `exiftags` or `exiftools` work well.

Comment: Is there any way to do exactly that but on a Windows laptop?

Comment: @y.g Sure replace it with a Mac  .  Actually, you can run exiftool on a PC. https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/  Don't know about the find command. You can install unix tools on a pc.

Answer (score 1):

[exiftool can also be used to generate a GPX](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html#Inverse) file which can be processed by other GPX-aware programs. You can download the `gpx.fmt` template from the [exiftool website](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html#Inverse):

```
exiftool -p ./gpx.fmt *JPG > output.gpx
```

Some useful options:

1. `-if` makes `exiftool` only process files with a gps tag,
2. `-fileOrder` allows processing in a forced order,
3. `-d` allows formatting the datatime string.

For example:

```
exiftool -if '$gpsdatetime' -fileOrder gpsdatetime -p ./gpx.fmt -d %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ *JPG > output.gpx
```